# Unit test for apex exception lines

Tags: apex, unit-test, community

[image]

Hi All,

Can anyone help me how to write unit test for apex exception? I assume red lines are not into code coverage. Let me correct if i am wrong

Comment: it would be great if you can update your question with your whole code.  in first sight I can see that if you will make userid length less than 1 it will cover that line.

Comment: Ok, this is same where i couldnt cover. public getUserInfo() {  
        user = [SELECT id, email, username, usertype, communitynickname, timezonesidkey, languagelocalekey, firstname, lastname, phone, title,
                street, city, country, postalcode, state, localesidkey, mobilephone, extension, fax, contact.email
                FROM User
                WHERE id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
                
             
          // guest users should never be able to access this page
        if (user.usertype == 'GUEST') {
            throw new NoAccessException();
        }

Comment: create a new test user inside your code and set user.usertype="Guest" while creating that user.

Comment: In this case i can not write usertype. But i re write the code to check for profile and user licence instead od usertype. So i created test user in a way to fall into this exception. Thanks to Kevin P. I had to create a correct test data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Morning.

The general pattern for testing exceptions is this:

1. Create your data.
2. Start the Test.
3. Create a boolean variable, DidThrowException = false.
4. Run your code inside a Try/Catch block.
5. Catch only the type of exception that your code throws. In this case, NoAccessException.
6. If the Catch block is run, set your boolean variable to True.
7. Stop your Test.
8. Assert that the boolean is true.
9. ... $$$